# Modify search result based on post type

Tags: wordpress, search, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking to modify WordPress search where based on the post type in the search results, either the post title will be linked to its detailed page or to a 3rd party website.

For instance, post type - 'publication' has a detail page where a user can read the publication in detail when they click on the post title. However, the post type - 'media', doesn't have a detail page but is linked to a 3rd party website and the 'website url' is a custom field.

Post type- publication -> detail page 
Post type- media ->3rd party website (website url)

Both the publication & media are custom plugins that we have created.

Here is the code I tried to write to get the custom field 'website_url' and link it to the the_title() but it doesn't work. It doesn't go into the while ( $the_query->have_posts()) loop.

```
If (post_type=="media")
{

$args = array(
                 'numberposts'  => -1,
                 'post_type'        => 'media',
                 'meta_query'   => array(
                 'relation'     => 'AND',
                 array(
                  'key'     => 'title', //post link
                  'compare' => '=',
                   'value'      => $posttitle
                    )
                     )
                   );

                 // query
               $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

  <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
<?php
 $link = get_field('website_url'); ?>
<div><h3><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
} //for each loop
                      } //if closes here
                         }
}
else
{
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
}
```

The result should be where when it is a media post, clicking on the post title will take the user to "website url" else to the detailed page.

Answer (score 0):

well you can just hook in "pre_get_post" and check for the post type there. Something in this fashion:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','search_filter' );
function search_filter( $query ) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'media' ){
        //change the post link here
      }
    }
  }
```

}

I hope this helps for more information please see this - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: I'm able to get the posts and it's IDs so far but I'm not able to change the post link to website_url. That is I'm able to know which posts are of media type in the search results but how to change the post link is the issue.

Comment: Something like : UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE( guid, 'oldurl', 'newurl') WHERE ID='$post_id

Comment: Yuxel, sorry, I'm not looking to replace old with new urls.

I'm looking to hyperlink the post title with a custom field- 'website_url' in the search result, in case the post type is 'media'.

I'm able to identify which post are media type but I do no know how to hyperlink the the_title() with the_field ('website_url').